# List declaration for sObject on target config property Lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-xml

So I have this component where I want to create a @api accesible variable containing Cases instead of Strings I was using, to be accessed from a visual Flow.

The whole thing was running smooth with another variable

```
<property name="selectedIds" type="String[]"/>

<property name="ticketsReturned" type="@salesforce/schema/Case[]"/>
```

The js is able to populate the values correctly but once i'm back in the flow and moving forward and pass this variable to a Apex method it's always null. So I assume the javascript is able to operate with the list but it cannot assign correctly the Case[] type to be accessed as such from the flow?

Is my syntax correct?

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly, but in this post 
https://unofficialsf.com/adding-lightning-web-components-to-flow-screens/
Provides example of what i'm trying to do on Contacts. He's assigning the value of a variable in the lwc to a variable in the flow.

Comment: Sorry I read the question badly. I think your syntax is correct. You can see an example http://www.salesforcelwc.in/use-lwc-in-flows.html - Maybe the flow logic that is setting the var is not correct?

Comment: Yeah, I assume that's the answer,so we can close this one as a duplicate, thanks for your help.